# How to compute the offset from column and line number ? - Go

Tags: go

I need to compute the offset in a source code file using a column and line number as reference (e.g. `source.go:23:42`). How can I compute the offset ?  I'm using it to analyse the source code with some go tools([oracle](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/oracle), [ast](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast) and [token](http://golang.org/pkg/go/token)).

Answer (score 2):

Since line width isn't fixed, there's no quick way of knowing that. you need to traverse the file's content character by character and count the offset. something like:

```
func findOffset(fileText string, line, column int) int {
   // we count our current line and column position
   currentCol := 1
   currentLine := 1


   for offset,ch := range fileText {
      // see if we found where we wanted to go to
      if currentLine == line && currentCol == column {
         return offset
      }

      // line break - increment the line counter and reset the column
      if ch == '\n' {
         currentLine++
         currentCol = 1
      } else {
          currentCol++
      }

    } 
    return -1; //not found
} 

// this here is our source code for example
var sampleText = `package main

var foo = "hello"

var bar ="world"
`


func main() {

      fmt.Println(findOffset(sampleText, 1, 1)) //prints 0

      fmt.Println(findOffset(sampleText, 3, 5)) //prints 18

}
```

Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/fWb9N9r9pi